# Best Practice to update computed fields on an xpage using managed beans

Tags: xpages

I have an xpage with several editable fields and need to update some computed fields dynamically.  I am using a managed bean to store all data, all the fields are bound to the bean.

For example sake, say there is an input called *input1*, and another called *input2*.  I would like to display the sum in a field dynamically, call this field *sum1*.  This field like the others is bound to the managed bean.

I was intending on using either a partial refresh or CSJS to update the *sum1* field, and a backend SSJS to write the value to the bean.  I also considered binding to a viewScope variable and then setting the bean on submit.  I know that I could get either option work, but I am looking for the best practice.

I ask this question because it occurred that since I was already using a bean that maybe my best approach should be to put this logic in the bean itself in the *setSum1()* and/or *getSum1()* methods.  Perhaps I have been reading too much of Jesse Gallagher's blog, but the thought of the MVC model and separating business logic are ringing in my head.

I hope this isn't too subjective, I am looking for the best practice from those who have more experience using beans than I.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steve,
if you have a bean, then you don't need to resort to SSJS. Just write a `getSum1()` function and bind to `#{yourBean.sum1}`. When you only have a get function the field automatically becomes readonly.

Comment: Stephan, I was hoping you would answer :)  I decided to log on tonight in case I needed to ask you a followup during your daytime, but I don't need to because I got it to work.  I would never have guessed the field automatically becomes read-only without the set method.  I was thinking the logic would go in the set method, not get, but it all makes sense now.  Thank You!