# Xpages - recalculate field when value of other fields change

Tags: xpages

I have an Xpage with several fields that the user needs to enter a dollar amount in. I would like to compute a total as the user changes values (we have all done this a lot in classic notes).

[image]

So I have two input fields with dollar amounts. I would like the last field to be recomputed whenever a user changes one of the first two values. That total field is bound to a total field on my form, and I don't want to change that until the user saves the document.

I know I need to write an on change event in the editable fields, but after that I am not sure what I to do?

Here is muy code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="xpExpenditures"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:panel id="panel1"><xp:inputText id="inputText4" value="#{document1.Funds01}" style="width:160.00px">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertNumber type="currency"></xp:convertNumber>
        </xp:this.converter>
        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial">
        </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:inputText><xp:br></xp:br>+<xp:br></xp:br><xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{document1.Funds02}" style="width:160.00px">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertNumber type="currency"></xp:convertNumber>
        </xp:this.converter>
        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panel1">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:inputText><xp:br></xp:br>=<xp:br></xp:br><xp:inputText id="inputText9" value="#{document1.Funds08}" style="width:160.00px" disabled="true">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertNumber type="number"></xp:convertNumber>
        </xp:this.converter>
    </xp:inputText></xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a much better user experience if you calculate the total amount right away on **client side** without going back to server with partial refresh every time a field changes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onClientLoad"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
function valueNumber(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    var val = elem.value ? (+(elem.value.replace("$", ""))).toFixed(2) : "";
    elem.value = val ? "$" + val : "";
    return +val;
}
calculate = function() {
    var val = valueNumber("#{id:inputTextFunds01}") + valueNumber("#{id:inputTextFunds02}");
    val = val ? "$" + val.toFixed(2) : "";
    document.getElementById("#{id:inputTextFunds08}").value = val;
    document.getElementById("#{id:inputTextDisabled}").value = val;
}]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument
            var="document1"
            formName="xpExpenditures"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:panel
        id="panel1">
        <xp:inputText
            id="inputTextFunds01"
            value="#{document1.Funds01}"
            style="width:160.00px">
            <xp:this.converter>
                <xp:convertNumber
                    type="currency"
                    currencySymbol="$">
                </xp:convertNumber>
            </xp:this.converter>
            <xp:eventHandler
                event="onchange"
                submit="false">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[calculate();]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:inputText>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        +
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:inputText
            id="inputTextFunds02"
            value="#{document1.Funds02}"
            style="width:160.00px">
            <xp:this.converter>
                <xp:convertNumber
                    type="currency"
                    currencySymbol="$">
                </xp:convertNumber>
            </xp:this.converter>
            <xp:eventHandler
                event="onchange"
                submit="false">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[calculate();]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:inputText>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        =
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:inputText
            id="inputTextFunds08"
            value="#{document1.Funds08}"
            style="display:none">
            <xp:this.converter>
                <xp:convertNumber
                    type="currency"
                    currencySymbol="$">
                </xp:convertNumber>
            </xp:this.converter>
        </xp:inputText>
        <xp:inputText
            id="inputTextDisabled"
            value="#{document1.Funds08}"
            style="width:160.00px"
            disabled="true">
        </xp:inputText>
    </xp:panel>
    <xp:button
        value="Save"
        id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete"
            immediate="false"
            save="true"></xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

This code writes the total amount on fields' change into the *visible* but *disabled* field "inputTextDisabled" and into a *hidden* but *editable* field "inputTextFunds08". Both are connected to document's field "Funds08". This way it gets saved with the new total amount on submit.

The example above does work for currency "$". Code would be easier if fields would be converted as number fields instead of currency fields and currency symbol would be placed outside the fields.

Answer (score 0):

**Using the way you describe:**

On both fields do a partial refresh in the onChange event.  (The partial refresh will have to be in all fields that you want to do the update if there are others.)  It is recommended to put the result fields in a separate panel and update that panel.  The panel should contain the field to update but not the editable fields that are used to calc the value.  Best to keep them separate, if you only have one then you can update the field instead of the panel.

**For consideration:**

Although there is nothing wrong with the above way, consider using a managed bean to store your objects and update the fields on your page.  You can keep your logic in one place and easily calculate the values dynamically.  You just modify the getter method have it calculate whenever the other fields change.  You won't need a setter method.

See this answer here.
[Best Practice to update computed fields on an xpage using managed beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331200/best-practice-to-update-computed-fields-on-an-xpage-using-managed-beans)

This is a summary blog post of my lessons learned:  http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/06/dynamic-computed-values-in-xpage.html
This assumes that the result is 'computed' and not an edit box like in your code, I am assuming here that you would want your calculated result to not be editable.

In both methods you still have to save your data, so the back end is not yet updated unless you specifically update it.